# Execute Remaining Arguments as Command

Tags: shell

Okay, so I have a fairly simple script that runs using various options until a special one is encountered (two hyphens), after which I'd like it to treat all remaining arguments as a command to be run.

For example:

```
do_something.sh Foo Bar -- printf '%s\n' "Done 'Foo' and 'Bar'"
```

In this case the script runs operations for `Foo` and `Bar` before executing a `printf` statement that should produce a single line of text.

What I'd like to know is what the best method for running the remaining arguments as a command would be?

Currently I'm processing them into an `eval` friendly string, because passing them in directly via `eval "$@"` doesn't seem to work properly as this actually breaks the `printf` command completely (instead of "Done 'Foo' and 'Bar'" on a line it outputs "DonenFoonandnBarn"). However processing the arguments for passing into `eval` as a single string is a bit messy as I have to process everything into a quote-safe form. I've also tried passing the arguments to `sh` or `bash` but these don't see commands like `printf` or `echo` as executable.

So is there a more direct method I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an `eval` here.  The “direct” way just works fine:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu

for arg in "$@"
do
    shift
    if [ "$arg" = '--' ]
    then
        break
    fi
    echo "Doing something else with argument '$arg'..."
done

# Execute the remainder as shell command.
"$@"
```

Saved as `demo.sh`:

```
$ ./demo.sh Foo Bar -- printf '%s\n' "Done 'Foo' and 'Bar'"
```

```
Doing something else with argument 'Foo'...
Doing something else with argument 'Bar'...
Done 'Foo' and 'Bar'
```

Since the string is expanded only once, the original tokenization stays intact.

If all you want to do is executing a command after another command completed successfully, you could also use

```
$ ./demo.sh Foo Bar && printf '%s\n' "Done 'Foo' and 'Bar'"
```

without altering the script itself.

Comment: Ugh *facepalms*, didn't know I could do that! As for why I'm doing this in the script itself, it's because it may not be invoked in an environment where `&&` or `;` are supported (for example, OS X's `launchd` system) as they would be treated as literals in that case, anyway, thanks for the answer!